# Unable to call my web service in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm facing some problem in calling my web service the code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function InfoByDate(email) {
        alert('dfgsdfgds'+email);
        var obj = { email: $("#txtEmail").val() };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:3319/FacebookServices.asmx/GetEmailId',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert('dxgfsd' + data);
                var a = data;
                if (a == "Create") {
                    alert('xyz');
                    alert('abc');
                } else if (a == "redirect") {
                    alert('jksdjkd');
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>

[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] 
    public static string GetEmailId(string email)
    {
        clsVolunteer objVol = new clsVolunteer();
        DataTable dtEmail = objVol.CheckEmailId(email);
        if (dtEmail == null)
        {
            return "Create";
        }
        else
        {
            return "redirect";
        }
    }
```

My first alert is working that means the function is getting called but not my 
web service. I dont know whats wrong.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

For that you should enable the ajax calling in your webservice.
Uncomment these lines to do so,

```
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

also try to give the relative path as url.
like
**/FacebookServices.asmx/GetEmailId**

Comment: i tried that but the result is same i'm not able to call

Comment: That is why im not able to debug it

Comment: did you try it with relative url?

Comment: the page is getting loaded with no errors...the items which had to be loaded by web service is null

Comment: Is there any other way to call the web service